# sbt fails to run when I try add the node modules in the project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I want to **include the node_modules in scala play project**. So, I added the following lines in my build sbt file as below( from [Import npm node_modules' css into Play Framework 2.4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475629/import-npm-node-modules-css-into-play-framework-2-4-app).But) when I run the sbt for the project it is giving error as below.

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "node_modules"
```

> import controllers.Assets
>   [error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type
>   error in expression  [error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in
>   expression [error] Use 'last' for the full log.

How shall I add the node_module resources to a play project and how shall i fix this issue.

When I delete the autogenerated import controllers.Assets sbt is running fine but after some time `import controllers.Assets` getting autoimported. I added the following in my .idea/sbt.xml.

> ```
> <SbtProjectSettings>
>             <option name="useAutoImport" value="false"/>
>         </SbtProjectSettings>
> ```

But still dosen't work it is again autoimporting.

How shall i fix these issues ?

How shall i include the node_modules in Play project in intellij ?

Answer (score 0):

I delete the .idea folder and reloaded that solved my problem, node modules are being loaded with

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "node_modules"
```